# Keycloak - Add Group IDs to Token

Tags: keycloak, identity

I have a Keycloak Client where i am receiving my Access Tokens. I have created a few mappers to gain some additional informations out of the Access Token. 
With the **Group Membership** Mapper type i can also receive the Group names as an array, where the user is a member of. But i want to have the IDs of the Groups.

Is it possible to add those to the Token instead of making an additional API call to Keycloak?

Comment: Were yuu ever able to figure this out? I too am trying to add an ID or something unique to the token for groups.